# Display time format as (MM/DD/YYYY - HH:MM AM/PM) - Django/Python

Tags: python, django, email, datetime, django-views

Under the "send_mail" function, I would like to change the "start" variable to display the date/time as MM/DD/YYYY - HH:MM AM/PM in the email. Does someone know how to do this?

Thank you in advance!

```
date = coerce_date_dict(request.GET)
initial_data = None
if date:
    try:
        start = datetime.datetime(**date)
        initial_data = {
            "start": start,
            "end": start + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)
        }
    except TypeError:
        raise Http404
    except ValueError:
        raise Http404

instance = None
if event_id is not None:
    instance = get_object_or_404(Event, id=event_id)

calendar = get_object_or_404(Calendar, slug=calendar_slug)

form = form_class(data=request.POST or None, instance=instance, initial=initial_data)

if form.is_valid():
    event = form.save(commit=False)
    if instance is None:
        event.creator = request.user
        event.calendar = calendar
        try:
            send_mail('New Lesson', '%s has scheduled a new lesson for %s' %(request.user.full_name, start), 'example@gmail.com', ['example@gmail.com'])
        except:
            pass
    event.save()
    next = next or reverse('event', args=[event.id])
    next = get_next_url(request, next)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`start` is a [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object, so we can call its [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) method to generate a formatted string.

The format specifier you want is `%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p`

For example, the `strftime` method called on the current time (for me, on the East Coast of US) generated: `03/17/2015 05:51 PM`

Which we can easily integrate into your code with:

```
start = datetime.datetime(**date)
initial_data = {
    "start": start.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"),
    "end": start + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)
}
```

Note: You'll have to ensure that making this change doesn't break anything else "down the road" -- as `initial_data['start']` *was* a `datetime.datetime` object, and is now a string.